# Definition of rational numbers

Tags: definition, rational-numbers, axioms, ordered-fields

We can uniquely define the set of real numbers as a complete ordered field. But can we do something similar with the set of rational numbers ? I think we need to change the completness axiom with some other one. I know that we can define integers in ordered field so maybe this axiom should state that every number is quotient of two integers ? Or maybe we can choose some simpler one. So what axiom/axioms should we choose instead of completness axiom to define rational numbers ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Your link directs to the wrong part of the article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can define the field of rational numbers as the smallest ordered field.

More precisely, let $F$ be an ordered field without subfields (except for $F$ itself). Then it is not hard to prove that

- $\mathbb Q$ is one such field;
- every such field is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: So $$\text{"$F$ is the smallest ordered field"}$$ is just a sloppy way to say$$\text{"$F$ is an ordered field without any subfields except for $F$ itself"}$$? This is not what I would have expected, that's why I'm asking for a confirmation.

Comment: @Filippo I *don't* think it is sloppy, but one should justify why such a smallest field exists.

Comment: I now agree that this is not sloppy. I didn't know that the intersection of two subfields is a subfield, but now this makes sense.